Excel: can you replicate/embed a cell in another worksheet (dynamically)
Sheet 1 has inputs: two columns of names and weights.
Sheet 2 shows data outputs based on the two columns, though the entries have been reordered based on several criteria.
I want to be able to make alterations to the weights in Sheet 2, as it is easier to see how it affects the outputs.
Currently, I have a column which you can enter changes and it increments the weight without altering the order.
However, if the data in Sheet 1 changes, then the order of Sheet 2 changes and so the incremental action column is now misaligned.
Is there a way to have this incremental action column essentially live in Sheet 1, so it doesn't move, but be editable from Sheet 2?
I am out of ideas for how to make the incremental column be an input that dynamically responds to the row it is in.

The answer is: probably/maybe.  But we can't give an answer without seeing a sample of the data on Sheet 1, the ordering criteria for Sheet 2, the formulas you are currently using to apply to the data, and other aspects concerning the details of your work. Sample data for 10-15 rows is probably enough.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
